# Clearing Eclipse's 'application cache' when performing launch (Run/Debug) for Eclipse Application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP project in Eclipse which I launch as an 'Eclipse Application'. After launching and playing with the application, I close it, make some more code modifications and launch again. When I launch the second time, the same changes in the application (tabs opened, fields highlighted...) remain the same as my previous launch. How can I get the Eclipse Application launcher to completely forget my previous run. I am already performing Project > Clean, and running Eclipse with -clean. I would like my 'eclipse application cache' to be cleaned for every run of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Run/Debug Configurations dialog, choose the configuration you want to change, go to *Main* tab, check the *Clear* checkbox inside *Workspace Data* group and select the *workspace* radio button.  Uncheck *Ask for confirmation before clearing* if you wish.